# Word that means 'do before'?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word `prefix` means a fragment that is attached to the beginning of a word, modifying it's meaning. Similarly, the word `prerequisite` is a requisite that is needed before the subject of the prerequisite. Is there a word that means "an action that modifies another action and takes place before said action"? Or simply, "an action that you do before (another action)"? For instance:

```
 Picking up a spoon is a (pre-action) of eating soup.
```

Where `pre-action` would be a substitute for the word I'm looking for.

(Bonus if there is a similar word paralleling 'suffix' meaning 'to take an action after (another action)'.)

Comment: How about *Picking up a spoon is **preparatory** to eating soup*?

Comment: @deadrat I thought about that but it feels more appropriate to say 'picking up a spoon is a preparatory action to eating soup'. I'm not sure this is the best example, honestly, because ideally the word indicates that the pre-action modifies the action, like a prefix modifies a word. And, I really would like a single word.

Comment: *Antecedent* has some of the qualities you're looking for.

Comment: @Lawerence Yes! That might be the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you need a noun? Otherwise, you might say, "Picking up a spoon *precedes* eating soup".

Comment: Technically, picking up a spoon is not a prerequisite for eating soup (you can drink it from the bowl). Regardless, though, even if it were a *requirement* that must be filled *beforehand*, and any given pre-action would also be a requirement, I'm looking for something specific to *doing*. A prerequisite could also be a condition of being, such as "being a citizen is a prerequisite for voting". I want to exclude this category of prerequisites.

Comment: It's a *preliminary* step or action, or just a *preliminary*.

Comment: Prepare: (Pre:word-forming element meaning "before," from Old French pre- and Medieval Latin pre-, both from Latin prae (adverb and preposition) "before in time or place"). ( pare: "to trim by cutting close," c. 1300, from Old French parer "arrange, prepare; trim, adorn," and directly from Latin parare "make ready, prepare, furnish, provide, arrange, order.) -from Online Etymology Dictionary.

Comment: The fact that teachers usually use the term _preparation_ possibly indicates that there isn't a more rigorously defined alternative.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for

> precursor

Although commonly used of a thing (the harpsichord is a precursor to the piano) it can also refer to actions or events.

Comment: Reason for downvote?